# Where is the .apk of a deployed PhoneGap app on the mobile device?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

After "cordova run android", you send your app to your mobile phone.

When you connect your phone to your computer, there is the following folder "Android -> data -> com.mydomain.myapp" then there was 2 folders "cache" and "files" but there is nothing.

So, Where is the apk of my application ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is where all the APKs are: in folder `/data/app`. You may not have permission to access that folder though.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer, but, why a lot of people said me, we can easily find the APK file and then unpack it ?

Comment: On a rooted phone it is trivially easy.

Comment: Rooted phone means super-user or Jailbreaked ?